# Can I remove the caption in a CDockablePane

Tags: c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I'm porting a MFC application to use the Ribbon UI and MFC feature pack and would like to have a docked horizontal pane that does not include a caption.  I'd hope that something like

```
MyPane.ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION, 0);
m_pParentFrame->RecalcLayout();
```

would work, but no joy.  FWIW, the docking pane is hosting a wide horizontal dialog docked under the main view and the caption wastes more desktop real estate than I'd like to give away.

**Edit:**  Further googling found a possible solution here: http://www.sibisa.com/remove-hide-title-bar-board-cdockablepane-window/

**Edit2:** EnableGripper(FALSE) was what was needed, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984118.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling **EnableGripper(FALSE)** removes the caption.